# How to debug crashing C++ library loaded in python project

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, ctypes

I am attempting to figure out why calling a function in a dynamically loaded lib crashes python. I'm doing the following, I have a C++ function in a dynamic library file, which is loaded in python using ctypes. I then call the function from python:

```
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary(libPath)

# Note: using c_char_p instead of POINTER(c_char) does not yield any difference in result
# Export const char* GetSection(const char* TilesetID, int32_t X0, int32_t Y0, int32_t X1, int32_t Y1, uint8_t*& OutData, uint64_t& OutDataSize)
lib.GetSection.argtypes = [POINTER(c_char), c_int32, c_int32, c_int32, c_int32, POINTER(c_void_p), POINTER(c_uint64)]
lib.GetSection.restype = POINTER(c_char)

output_data = c_void_p()
output_size = c_uint64()
str_data = lib.GetSection(id.encode('ascii'), x0, y0, x1, y1, byref(output_data), byref(output_size))
```

On MacOS, this works exactly as expected. Unfortunately on Windows 11, it does not. I'm running from a Jupyter notebook and the kernel crashes and restarts immediately after the `lib.GetSection` call.

I have attached the Visual Studio debugger to the process, and can see that on the C++ side of things, the function is being correctly called, all parameters are correct, and it returns without error. It is at this point that the python kernel crashes, deep in a python call stack that I don't have symbols for.

How do I even approach debugging this? Does anything look wrong with the way I am calling the function?

Comment: Is the C++ function written correctly?  You haven't shown it so we can't reproduce the issue.  If it returns, say, a pointer to a stack variable instead of allocated on the heap, undefined behavior would occur.  That would explain working on one OS and failing on another.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Python crashes immediately upon return, before any other python calls happen. I suppose it could be copying the return to `str_data`, I'll test that, but I use the same technique in other functions and it has no issue.

Comment: Btw, the python installer contains debug symbols, but they are not installed by default. You need to select the checkbox in the installer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a toy C++ function to demonstrate your problem would help.  Below is a best guess C++ function with the same signature and the Python code to call it:

test.cpp

```cpp
#include <cstdint>

#define API __declspec(dllexport)

extern "C" {

API const char* GetSection(const char* TilesetID, int32_t X0, int32_t Y0, int32_t X1,
                           int32_t Y1, uint8_t*& OutData, uint64_t& OutDataSize) {
    OutData = new uint8_t[5] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    OutDataSize = 5;
    return "hello";
}

API void Delete(uint8_t* OutData) {
    delete [] OutData;
}

}
```

test.py

```py
import ctypes as ct

dll = ct.CDLL('./test')
# Note change to 2nd to last argument.
dll.GetSection.argtypes = (ct.c_char_p, ct.c_int32, ct.c_int32, ct.c_int32, ct.c_int32,
                           ct.POINTER(ct.POINTER(ct.c_uint8)), ct.POINTER(ct.c_uint64))
dll.GetSection.restype = ct.c_char_p

def GetSection(tileid, x0, y0, x1, y1):
    output_data = ct.POINTER(ct.c_uint8)()
    output_size = ct.c_uint64()
    str_data = dll.GetSection(tileid, x0, y0, x1, y1,
                              ct.byref(output_data), ct.byref(output_size))
    out_data = output_data[:output_size.value] # create a Python list of the data
    dll.Delete(output_data)  # can delete the data now
    return str_data, out_data

print(GetSection(b'id', 1, 2, 3, 4))
```

Output:

```
(b'hello', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Comment: Using `output_data = POINTER(c_uint8)()` instead of `output_data = c_void_p()`, and switching the second to last `argtype` to `POINTER(POINTER(c_uint8))` instead of `POINTER(c_void_p)` made all the difference, the call now completes correctly. Thank you!

Comment: I assumed that `POINTER(c_void_p)` would be interchangeable with other pointer types. I guess not. Also, since you seem to be a ctypes expert, what is the purpose of `c_char_p`, and is there any reason to use it as opposed to `POINTER(c_char)`?

Comment: @BWG Actually, using what you had should've worked.  It is compatible except for needing to cast the output pointer to something that can read the data.  I put it in my code as you had it, added the cast, and it worked fine.

Comment: @BWG In a callback parameter or return value, `c_char_p` is converted to a Python `bytes` object and the original pointer is lost.  If you need the pointer, such as in a callback needing to write to a buffer passed in, or to free a heap-allocated pointer as a return value, `POINTER(c_char)` remains a pointer that can be written to or passed to other functions.